# AKS Cluster - Intermittent Delays in API response due to DNS Queries

Tags: kubernetes, dns, azure-aks

We have hosted our microservice in Azure Kubernetes Service(Kubernetes v1.18). When the call (SOAP) is made from our microservice to an external API hosted on AWS using DNS name, we are observing latency in receiving the response intermittently.

We believe this is because the DNS resolution result is not cached for subsequent calls.
Same SOAP calls work fine when made from any resource outside our AKS cluster. We started observing this issue after we manually rotated AKS certificates.
Can you please give us some pointers to resolve this issue?

We checked with team managing external API, they confirmed that it's not an issue with AWS.
Setting dnsPolicy: Default in deployment yaml reduces the DNS queries but still ttl is very short.